# How can I properly uncheck items in a Qtablewiget based on a condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I created a table widget with three columns. The table is inside of a qwizard. It gets populated by reading a file and putting the lines of that file in its first column. It  looks like the pic below. Basically I would like the program to behave this way:

1. If both **`remove half of item`** and **`remove all of item`** are checked, uncheck `remove half of item` leaving only `remove all of item` for the row.Then add the line to the file.

   Execute it by pressing the OK button
2. Otherwise if only  `remove half of item` or `remove all of item` are checked. Add the line to the file.

   Execute it by pressing the OK button

**The problem is that it ends up with my desired output but only if I press Ok multiple times**
The functions that handles the behavior are `def print_checked(self):` and `def setChoice(self, item):`

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class TablePage(QtGui.QWizardPage):
    def __init__( self, parent=None):
        super(TablePage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.isWrittenTo = False
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)

        self.configureTable(self.table)
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()

        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(self)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)

        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.print_checked)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.close)
        self.choice = []

        self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.setChoice)




    def configureTable(self, table):
        rowf = 0
        rowx = 0
        table.setColumnCount(3)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("Whole items"))
        table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("remove half of item"))
        table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("remove all of item"))
        header = table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setResizeMode(0, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setResizeMode(1, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        item_list = []

        with open("/home/test1/items.txt") as in_file:
            if in_file is not None:
                xvar = in_file.readlines()
            for line in xvar:
                item_list.append(line)
                rowf += 1

        table.setRowCount(rowf)

        for linex in item_list:
            x = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            table.setItem(rowx, 0, x)
            rowx += 1
            x.setText(linex)
        for column in range(3):
            for row in range(rowf):
                if column % 3:
                    self.item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(column)
                    self.item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable |
                                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                    self.item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                    self.item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
                    table.setItem(row, column, self.item)

    def setChoice(self, item):
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.choice.append(item)
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked:
            self.choice.remove(item)

    def print_checked(self):
        path = '/home/test1/items-to-mod.txt'
        mode = 'a' if self.isWrittenTo else 'w'
        user = self.table
        if len(self.choice) > 0:
            with open(path, mode) as f:
                for item in self.choice:
                    delete = user.horizontalHeaderItem(item.column()).text()
                    if delete == "remove all of item" and user.item(item.row(), 1).checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                        user.item(item.row(), 1).setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                        print ('%s' % user.item(item.row(), 0).text() + 'is marked for %s' % delete)
                        f.write('fully remove %s' % user.item(item.row(), 0).text())
                    elif delete == "remove half of item":
                        print ('%s' % user.item(item.row(), 0).text() + 'is marked for %s' % delete)
                        f.write('remove half of %s' % user.item(item.row(), 0).text())
                    elif delete == "remove all of item":
                        print ('%s' % user.item(item.row(), 0).text() + 'is marked for %s' % delete)
                        f.write('fully remove %s' % user.item(item.row(), 0).text())
                    else:
                        print('%s' % item.text())
                        print (item.row(), item.column())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wizard = QtGui.QWizard()
    tablepage = TablePage()
    wizard.addPage(tablepage)
    wizard.button(QtGui.QWizard.NextButton).clicked.connect(tablepage.print_checked)
    wizard.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I can not understand your requirements. In both cases is the line added to the file? And in the first case: is the check removed only in remove half of item?

Comment: Yes, the line gets added to the file but I have to keep pressing the Ok button for it to show the proper output in the file

Comment: One other thing, If you know a way to center the check boxes in the table cells that would be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code repeated actions when unchecked, to make the improvement code the possible outputs: if it is marked the first add a 1 = 2 ** 0, if it is marked the second add 2 = 2 ** 1, therefore there will only be 4 Cases per row: [0, 2 ** 0, 2 ** 1, 2 ** 0 + 2 ** 1] = [0, 1, 2, 3]

change:

```
    def print_checked(self):
        path = '/home/test1/items-to-mod.txt'
        mode = 'a' if self.isWrittenTo else 'w'
        user = self.table
        d = dict([(x, 0) for x in range(self.table.rowCount())])

        for item in self.choice:
            d[item.row()] += 2 ** (item.column() - 1)

        text = ""
        for row, value in d.iteritems():
            if value == 3:  # They are both checked
                print("fully remove %s" % user.item(row, 0).text())
                user.item(row, 1).setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                text += 'fully remove %s' % user.item(row, 0).text()
            elif value == 2:    # only second is checked
                print('fully remove of %s' % user.item(row, 0).text())
                text += 'fully remove %s' % user.item(row, 0).text()
            elif value == 1:    # only first is checked
                print("remove half of %s" % user.item(row, 0).text())
                text += 'remove half of %s' % user.item(row, 0).text()

        with open(path, mode) as f:
            f.write(text)
```

Output:

[image]

after clicked OK:

[image]

```
fully remove a

fully remove of b

remove half of c
```

Comment: You should explain what the OP did wrong and ideally (ie if possible, ie just a couple of blocks of code changed) post only the code that needs changing since SO does not support side-by-side diffs.

Comment: It works exactly as I liked but might you be able to explain how this line of code works? I have an idea but not entirely sure `d = dict([(x, 0) for x in range(self.table.rowCount())])

        for item in self.choice:
            d[item.row()] += 2 ** (item.column() - 1)`

Comment: A ** k = {a * a * a * ... * a} k times

Comment: Well done but I think the list comprehension and power formula make the approach difficult to understand.

Comment: @Schollii 
I am only coding with 1 and 0, for example if both are marked: 11, if I only set the first, 01, if I set the second, 10, if none, 00, if we consider that they are numbers in binary.

Comment: I realize that. I should have said "more difficult to understand than necessary".

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would change is the setChoice: it should reflect the status more clearly, by storing for each row that has at least one check, the status: half (1), full (2), or both (1+2=3):

```
def setChoice(self, item):
    row = item.row()
    if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        self.choice.setdefault(row, 0)
        self.choice[row] += item.column()
        print(item, row, self.choice[row])

    else:
        assert item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
        self.choice[row] -= item.column()
        print(item, row, self.choice[row])
        # if checked state is now 0, remove it (could instead leave it
        # but filter on checked==0 in print_checked):
        if self.choice[row] == 0:
            del self.choice[row]
```

This requires some changes to the `print_checked`. There are many ways to do that, but I like to make code reflect intent: you need to "fix" or "adjust" a row that has 2 checkmarks; then process as usual. I also simplified some of your format strings. Result is:

```
with open(path, mode) as f:
    for item_row, checked in self.choice.items():
        item_text = user.item(item_row, 0).text()
        if checked == 3:  # delete == "remove all of item" and user.item(item.row(), 1).checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            # need to fix it!
            item_half = user.item(item_row, 1)
            item_half.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            checked = 2
            f.write('fixing %s\n' % item_text)

        delete = user.horizontalHeaderItem(checked).text()
        if checked == 1:  # delete == "remove half of item":
            f.write ('%s is marked for %s\n' % (item_text, delete))
            f.write('remove half of %s\n' % item_text)

        elif checked == 2:  # delete == "remove all of item":
            f.write ('%s is marked for %s\n' % (item_text, delete))
            f.write('fully remove %s\n' % item_text)

        else:
            f.write('%s\n' % item_text)
            f.write(item_row, checked)
```

Comment: @ Schollii Thanks